# Is there any free medical or clinical reports/corpus?

Tags: text, dataset, report, corpus, snomed-ct

I am doing a research on Clinical Natural language processing.
Is there any clinical report that contains sentences, patient conditions, patient history, clinical terms, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MIMIC](https://mimic.physionet.org/) database is a fantastic resource to test your clinical NLP. You will have apply to get access. Bear in mind that MIMIC is ICU data so those notes can differ from what you would see in PCP notes.

Other sources:

- [I2B2](https://www.i2b2.org/NLP/DataSets/Main.php) not sure if this is still downloadable
- [TREC](http://www.trec-cds.org/) Clinical Decision Support Track

Answer (score 3):

This could be what you're after: http://mtsamples.com/